# Ruby Sinatra Session Management Available in Class Methods?

Tags: ruby, class, session, sinatra

Just wondering if the scope of a session is manageable inside a custom object.  I'm getting the following error while trying to set a session variable inside a method for a user:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<User:0x007fd6f4117ba0>
file: user.rb location: log_in line: 315
```

Would be nice to be able to toss session management inside methods instead of the routes.  Using Sinatra's sessions:

`enable :sessions`

Comment: I'd be curious to know a better solution, but as a workaround you can pass `method(:session)` as an argument and then `.call`

Comment: @maxple what is the benefit of your trick against simply passing the `session` object as an argument?

Comment: @To마SE in this case you're right but for other stuff like `render`that wouldn't work

Comment: Essentially, it is open to rolling your own session sniffing.  Sinatra should provide that.  No mention in 2.0. I'm still investigating into this.  I'm new to Ruby.

Comment: Would passing the session object to the method an option for you? Reason why `sessions` is not available is that methods don't preserve the execution environment (ala a lambda/closure), and adding such feature might cause more problems than it solves. But if you think it should exist in some form, please open a feature request on github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enable sessions first in your class service.

enable :sessions
  set :session_secret
....